# Module not reloading after JSON.parse error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular, ecmascript-6

I have a test page for QA where our QA can replicate the behavior of the server by passing json to a mock service. 
Everything works as intended when I use a valid json, but when I use an invalid json I receive an error, which is regular. The problem I have is that the page doesn't update anymore after this json error, even with a valid json.

Here is an extract of the test page component:

```
export class QaTestComponent implements OnInit {
  modules: Module[];
  pageState: PageState;
  mockModulesValue: string;
  mockPageStateValue: string;

  constructor(private moduleService: MockModuleService, private pageStateService: MockPageStateService) { }

  getModules() {
    this.moduleService.getModules().then(modules => this.modules = modules);
  }

  updateModules() {
    let jsonModules = JSON.parse(this.mockModulesValue);
    this.moduleService.setModules(jsonModules);
    this.getModules();
  }
```

Here is the html file with the function call:

```
  <div class="qa-test-interface-setup-datas-type col-md-6">
    <h3 class="qa-test-interface-setup-datas-type-title">Modules</h3>
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="qa-test-interface-setup-datas-type-textarea" [(ngModel)]="mockModulesValue"></textarea>
    <button class="qa-test-interface-setup-datas-type-button" (click)="updateModules()">Update</button>
  </div>
```

And here is the mock service:

```
export class MockModuleService implements ModuleService {
  raw: Module[] = aJsonArray;
  response: Module[] = this.raw;

  setModules(mockModules: Module[]) {
    this.response = mockModules == null ? this.raw : mockModules;
  }

  getModules(): Promise<Module[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(this.response);
  }
}
```

I tried logging to see if a valid mockModuleValues was blocked in a component or a service after an error but I can see it goes through until getModules().

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I came to the point where I did my json parsing inside a try/catch to avoid the error killing my subscriber.

```
   updateModules() {    
     if(this.mockModulesValue) {
        try {
          let jsonModules = JSON.parse(this.mockModulesValue);
          this.moduleService.setModules(jsonModules);
          this.getModules();
        } catch(e) {
          alert(e);
        }
     }
   }
```